# Intercepting exceptions

Tags: java, swing, exception, intercept

I'd like to use to a custom exception to have a user-friendly message come up when an exception of any sort takes place.

What's a good straightforward way of doing this? Are there any extra precautions I should take to avoid interfering with Swing's EDT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Exception Translation:**

It's a good idea to not pollute your application with messages that have no meaning to the end user, but instead create **meaningful Exceptions** and messages that will translate the exception/error that happened somewhere deep in the implementation of your app.

As per @Romain's comment, you can use [Exception(Throwable cause)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.Throwable)) constructor to keep track of the lower level exception.

From `Effective Java 2nd Edition`, Item 61:

> [...] higher layers should catch
>   lower-level exceptions and, in their
>   place, throw exceptions that can be
>   explained in terms of the higher-level
>   abstraction. This idiom is known as
>   exception translation:

```
   // Exception Translation
    try {
         // Use lower-level abstraction to do our bidding
         ...
    } catch(LowerLevelException e) {
         throw new HigherLevelException(...);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Just make sure you pass in your original exception to the constructor of the new one so you can see the full stack trace as well as the original cause.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` which catches all exceptions you haven't cared for yourself

```
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;

   public class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

   public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
       Frame.showError("Titel", "Description", e, Level.WARNING);
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

register it in your app:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
}
```

and in your GUI you can use `org.jdesktop.swingx.JXErrorPane` from [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) to show a nice error popup, which informs the user about exceptions.

```
public static void showError(String title, String desc, Throwable e,
        Level level) {
    JXErrorPane.showDialog(this, new ErrorInfo(title,
            desc, null, null, e, level, null));
}
```